# Change cursor to pointer in echart's canvas

Tags: echarts

I got a gauge defined like this:

```js
{
  type: 'gauge',
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
  startAngle: 180,
  endAngle: 0,
  itemStyle: {
      color: '#6b7280',
  },
  pointer: {
      width: 2,
      length: '65%',
      offsetCenter: ['0', '8%']
  },
  progress: {
      show: true,
      overlap: true,
      roundCap: true
  },
  axisLine: {
      lineStyle: {
          width: 5,
          color: [
              [0.75, '#71717a'],
              [1, '#a1a1aa']
          ]
      },
  },
  splitLine: {
      show: false,
      distance: 0,
      length: 10
  },
  axisLabel: {
      show: false
  },
  axisTick: {
      show: false
  },
  detail: {
      show: false,
  },
  radius: '100%',
  center: ['50%', '75%'],
},
```

[image]

I'd like to change the cursor of the chart's canvas element to be a pointer but I don't find anything in the docs about this.

If I hover the canvas, the cursor is the default OSX-cursor.